# XLST creates an empty space after convert to html

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I don´t get it.

My xml input:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <results>
    <error file="mixed.cpp" line="11" id="unreadVariable" severity="style"          msg="Variable 'wert' is assigned a value that is never used."/>
    <error file="mixed.cpp" line="13" id="unassignedVariable"         severity="style" msg="Variable 'b' is not assigned a value."/>
    <error file="mixed.cpp" line="11" id="arrayIndexOutOfBounds" severity="error" msg="Array 'wert[2]' accessed at index 3, which is out of bounds."/>
    <error file="mixed.cpp" line="15" id="uninitvar" severity="error" msg="Uninitialized variable: b"/>
    <error file="mixed.cpp" line="5" id="unusedFunction" severity="style" msg="The function 'func' is never used."/>
    <error file="*" line="0" id="unmatchedSuppression" severity="style" msg="Unmatched suppression: missingIncludeSystem"/>
    </results>
```

using this xsl file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="error">
    <tr>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="@file"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="@line"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="@test"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="@severity"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="@msg"/></td>
    </tr>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But the first line I get is empty:

```
empty line
<tr><td>mixed.cpp</td><td>11</td><td/><td>style</td><td>Variable 'wert' is assigned a value that is never used.</td></tr>
```

Where is the empty line coming from?

Comment: add `<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>` before xsl:output. Test and see.

Comment: With your structure, there should also be a trailing empty line and an empty line between each matching `error`. Once you remove the whitespace, the `<tr>` will not start on a new line anymore, unless you add `indent="yes"` on `xsl:output`. Also, use `method="html"` if your target is HTML. It will take care of (non-)auto-closing elements that otherwise browsers would choke on. I.e. `<p></p>` vs `<p/>` and `<script></script>` vs `<script/>`.

Comment: Also remember that your current stylesheet will not produce well-formed XML output if you have more than one `error`, as it will output several `tr` elements with no containing root-level element.  An additional template like `<xsl:template match="/"><tbody><xsl:apply-templates select="results/error"/></tbody></xsl:template>` would fix both this problem (by creating a root `tbody`) and also the original blank line (by not applying any templates to the whitespace text nodes).

Answer (score 2):

The default template kicks in for templates not matching your `error` template, and the default template just outputs the text. Since you have whitespace text nodes, and you are not matching `results`, the whitespace inside `results` (and before and after `error`) will become part of the output.

There are multiple ways to fix this. A typical method is to write a low priority template that matches text that you do not want to match. I.e., if you add the following, your whitespace will disappear:

```
<xsl:template match="text()" />
```

Another approach would be to positively match your structure. I.e., if you would add the following, the whitespace also disappears, because now you match the root element and subsequently only apply templates on the elements that you are interested in (and not also the text nodes under `results`).

```
<xsl:template match="results">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="error" />
</xsl:template>
```

A third approach would be to add a whitespace-stripping declaration, but this may influence the input XML if your actual stylesheet is larger and would depend on whitespace elsewhere. This would only strip the whitespace on the `results` element:

```
<xsl:strip-space elements="results"/>
```

All three solution work, it depends on your project as a whole which one is most suitable.

Remember that in XSLT 1.0 and XSLT 2.0 non-matching nodes will be matched by the default template (which is invisible) and simply outputs the text value of that node. In XSLT 3.0 you have more control over this process:

```
<!-- XSLT 3.0 only -->
<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-skip" />
```